# Seeking easy to use web GIS stack for making fictional maps

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations

I am looking for a technology stack that would allow me to have some sort of OSM-driven custom map with as-easy-as-possible editing via a web frontend. I would require this for creating custom fictional maps for roleplaying games, so they wouldn't have any connection to the real world at all.

As for editing capabilities, I'm eyeing openstreetmap.org's current default web editor, iD. But to be honest, I have no idea what software I would need to make it all work together. I also have only limited knowledge when it comes to setting up virtual machines.

Does a ready-to-go appliance exists somewhere (or something that requires only trivial extra effort)?

By "fictional map" I mean exactly that, a completely made-up map that very likely doesn't re-use a single node from Earth's actual map but instead is made-up from ground zero. I intend to use OSM for this, mostly because of the easily transferable data format, my (limited but still somewhat present) acquaintance with editing and the vast landscape of readily available mapping/rendering tools. I do intend to use *most* tags as they would be used on OSM, so editor presets are fine as they are for Earth's non-fictional map.

It *should* be web-based as we're physically scattered through-out the world. If we only passed an .osm file around, I fear that we could bump into very inconsistent vaguely different versions of said fictional map too easily.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple out of the box experience, try the OpenGeoSuite: http://boundlessgeo.com/. (currently OpenGeoSuite doesn't exist anymore since Boundless has been bought by Planet, so this way wont work)

It will take a lot of work to get stuff working really nicely, but what you will want to do is:

- Decide on layers that make up your map, define attributes for those (schema)
- Set up all those layers in GeoServer, including styling
- If you have QGIS, you can connect into the PostGIS database directly to do editing
- Otherwise, the OGS has a web-based editing interface called GeoExplorer, which you can use to edit layers. This can handle the authentication aspects to allow folks to edit.

Is there something easier? I reckon doing it with a Desktop GIS first, something like QGIS, would get you started. Then you can move it to the OGS for maintenance and enhancement.

Actually, a first consideration is a coordinate system, but I'd just stick to web-mercator, 900913 or 3857.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to **stay at OSM side**. They cover all you need:

- editors
- data formats
- database+API
- renderers and exporters

Usually they are a bit more user friendly and less static than in the traditional GIS scene :)

If you work alone, you can easily use the [JOSM editor](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM), to download a certain region, erase everything, start mapping your own stuff but don't upload it to the OSM servers. Instead, you save it as .osm file (which is XML format) and can be rendered offline e.g. with [maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) or [tilemill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tilemill).

If you wan't/need to work as a team, you need to setup the rails port which drives osm.org and the database API. I heared it's not that easy, but possible to setup. Then your editors need to change the API URL to your server and can create a world from scratch. You might also start working with the [DEV servers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_the_dev_server) that will erase the content frequently

P.S. In GIS you map in a coordinate system -> needs to be considered and planned how your world/planet should look like